# GridView always craches when scrolling down

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data, gridview

I want to fill up a gridView with data. I am doing this with data I get back from a webservice. For filling up I have a property loopIndex that counts which object of an array should be the next cell. You can see the method CellForRowAtIndexPath over here.

```
- (NRGridViewCell*)gridView:(NRGridView *)gridView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyCellIdentifier = @"MyCellIdentifier";

    NRGridViewCell* cell = [gridView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyCellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[NRGridViewCell alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:MyCellIdentifier];

        [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.]];
        [[cell detailedTextLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.]];

    }
    NSLog(@"loopIndex: %d",_loopIndex);
    _players = [self getTeam];

       NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[_players objectAtIndex:_loopIndex]valueForKey:@"image"]]];
       UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imgData];
       cell.imageView.image = image;
        cell.textLabel.text = [[_players objectAtIndex:_loopIndex]valueForKey:@"name"];
        cell.detailedTextLabel.text = [[_players objectAtIndex:_loopIndex]valueForKey:@"position"];
    if(_loopIndex < [[self getTeam]count]){
    _loopIndex++;
    }else {
        _loopIndex = _loopIndex;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Here you see the error. It's always crashes on the NSData line.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[_PFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (30) beyond bounds (30)'
```

I think there is a problem with my loopIndex. Because when I just use a static value.  Let say 1O Like this

```
 cell.textLabel.text = [[_players objectAtIndex:_loopIndex]valueForKey:@"name"];
```

It won't crash. Does anybody knows how I can work around it?

Kind regards

Comment: Did you try putting a break point on it and stepping through the code to see where it's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    _loopIndex++;
    if(_loopIndex >= [[self getTeam]count]){
        _loopIndex = [[self getTeam]count]-1;
    }
```

Do do it properly you should do as following:

```
cell = // new default cell;

// calculate _loopindex for next attempt
if (_loopindex < [[self getTeam]count])
{
    //do your job
}

return cell;
```

If you set properly numbers of rows in section and in table you should have the method `gridView cellForItemAtIndexPath` invoked exact number of times as it is required. No more and no less. This will prevent you from returning nil or miscalculating `_loopindex` counter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is still crashes with the same error.

Comment: Just calculate loop index correctly Check if the table is proper length. Check if grid view is invoked required number of times.

Answer (score 0):

You are miscalculating `_loopindex` that's why you get an error but more importantly you should rely on the `indexPath` variable and not the index you are computing to display your data in this protocol method.